# wp_unregister and wp_enqueue

Tags: jquery, wordpress

it's been suggested to me to use wp_unregister and wp_enqueue to replace wordpress jquery library with a google hosted one (because the wordpress one was having some problems)

However, when i try to insert these into my wordpress site, it breaks my site.

Do I need to wrap them somehow?

```
wp_unregister_script('jquery');
wp_unregister_script('jquery-ui-core');

wp_enqueue_script('jquery', https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core', https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js);
```

My site has a custom folder where I can put custom functions. I tried this unsuccessfully

```
function googlejqueryhost(){


<?php
wp_unregister_script('jquery');
wp_unregister_script('jquery-ui-core');

wp_enqueue_script('jquery', https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core', https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js);


?>
}
add_action('wp_head', 'googlejqueryhost');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code I've [demonstrated in this blog post](http://beneverard.co.uk/blog/wordpress-loading-jquery-correctly/), how about this:

```
function load_jquery() {

    // only use this method is we're not in wp-admin
    if (!is_admin()) {

        // deregister the original version of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');

        // discover the correct protocol to use
        $protocol='http:';
        if($_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on') {
            $protocol='https:';
        }

        // register the Google CDN version
        wp_register_script('jquery', $protocol.'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.5.2');

        // add it back into the queue
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    }

}

add_action('template_redirect', 'load_jquery'
```

I use the template redirect hook, I wonder if that is what is causing your issues.

Either way if this doesn't work can you give more info on the issue, have you got a link to the site?

**Edit**

Oh, also your function opens up PHP tags when really they should already be open, see my comments...

```
function googlejqueryhost(){


<?php // HERE, remove this
wp_unregister_script('jquery');
wp_unregister_script('jquery-ui-core');

wp_enqueue_script('jquery', https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core', https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js);


?> // AND HERE, remove this
}
```

**Edit 2**

You'll notice your site is now correctly loading jQuery from Google's CDN, the other script has nothing to do with the jQuery library itself.

[image]

Comment: o.k, thanks, I will try it, do I do exactly the same thing for jquery-ui?

Comment: by the way, i tried my custom function without opening php tags and it still didn't work

Comment: Yup, you can do the same for jQuery UI too. Did you change the hook to 'template_redirect'? Can you explain how it's breaking your site, does the Google CDN script URL appear in your page source?

Comment: O.K, I added it, but check this out www.englishgod.com if you look at the source code, it shows the Google hosted jquery but also directly above that it shows the core wordpress jquery being accessed <script type="text/javascript" src="http://englishgod.com/wp-includes/js/l10n.js?ver=20101110"></script>

Comment: I was getting a server error when I tried the functions in my OP

Comment: No, it's only outputting the Google version, no local version at all is being loaded. Better yet jQuery is definitely loaded.

Comment: thanks, do you mind explaining to a newbie how you know that it's only outputting Google version, since I can see this local version in my header <script type="text/javascript" src="http://englishgod.com/wp-includes/js/l10n.js?ver=20101110"></script>  btw, i added the jquery ui too

Comment: It appears to be working now (see my last edit), I was able to use jQuery to hide all your links using Chrome's Inspector.

Comment: Certainly, when you open the resource (try both scripts for fun) if it's jQuery it'll have a comment at the top, like this `/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library`, the first one doesn't, and it;s only 3 lines long... certainly not the jQuery library :-)