# use javascripts objects into a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I save an html page that has an image rotator that work by using javascript, and after I save it work correctly.
I convert this html page to a wordpress theme but the rotator don't work anymore.

what's the problem?
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress insert embeded jquery script using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).
Check that jQuery inserted just one time in your theme! You can disable auto insertion by adding this code in **function.php** file:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

and take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597034/wp-unregister-and-wp-enqueue).

Comment: it's not my solution, my java scripts isn't jquery. and i need  wp_enqueue_script  for some plugins like wp-poll

Comment: Please Write a link or something else to somebody can see the code!
P.S. This is better for [wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) questions